# Javascript Regular Expression for nested CSS classes

Tags: javascript, css, regex

following my question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12424357/javascript-and-regular-expression-for-private-use-area-pua-characters), I have been trying to write a similar bit of code in Javascript that would detect a range of Unicode characters occurring in the text from nested CSS classes. So far, I was able to make it work on DIV Classes, for instance:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('h2.ClassName').each(function(index, DOMElement){
        if(/[\uE000-\uF8FF]+/.test($(DOMElement).text())) {
            $(this).removeClass('ClassName').addClass('CSS-ClassName');
        }
    }) 
});
```

However, a similar Javascript does not work on the following classes:

```
<ul>
    <h4 class="ClassName">Text</h4>
    <li class="ClassName">Text</li>
<ul>
```

Any idea?

Thanks indeed,

Regards,

I.

Comment: Use only the classname instead of 'h2.classname'.

Comment: @ilariac , There is no h2 element in your code . is it h4?

Comment: @Mayilarun, bharathi, the Javascript code for  h2.classname works fine, however I cannot use a similar approach for UL Classes. The HTML example is to show how those particular classes are nested. Hope this would explain this better. I.

Comment: just as a side note, you shouldn't have your h4 placed within a UL element.. I get that it's a random example however.

Comment: @pebbl, I do agree with you. I was not the one who wrote it...

Answer (score 1):

If you want jQuery to find other elements using the same `ClassName` then you need to add them to your selector, like so:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('h2.ClassName, h4.ClassName, li.ClassName').each(function(index, DOMElement){
        if(/[\uE000-\uF8FF]+/.test($(DOMElement).text())) {
            $(this).removeClass('ClassName').addClass('CSS-ClassName');
        }
    }) 
});
```

If you want to get really generic, and change all elements with `ClassName` then you would change the selector to:

```
/* ... */
$('.ClassName').each(); /* ... you get the idea ... */
/* ... */
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: thanks for your reply. Unfortunately, my issue gets slightly more complicated when I have the following HTML elements: 

<div class="Class">
<ul>
<li>
<strong> Title: </strong> Text to detect
</li>
....

The above solution does not seem to work...

Thanks, I.

Comment: Have you tried `$(this).text()` instead of `$(DOMElement).text()`? I don't think it's the problem, but worth a shot.

Comment: +1 Ilariac's answer seems to work from what I can see: http://jsfiddle.net/bzHxT/1/ - when running in FireFox 16 Mac OSX I get each item ending up with a red border... which is what should be happening - at least in my example - should it not?

Comment: Hi all, thanks for your help. Yes, it works in case <li> elements are associated to a class. Unfortunately, it does not in case those elements have no classes associated. See [this] (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12641673/javascript-regular-expressions-for-li-elements) for more info. Thanks again for your replies! I.

Comment: @ilariac In that case then you just need to target the elements you require using their tagname instead. `$('.ClassName li')` for example. Or if you'd prefer you could target all elements within a .ClassName element using `$('.ClassName *')`